# Validation layer in PHP and DB interaction

Tags: php, validation, model-view-controller, domain-driven-design, solid-principles

In input of my application I have the following data: *airplane_id*, *airport_id* and *passenger(s)* details.

I need to make sure that selected *airplane_id* could reach *airport_id*. It might be done only with help a SQL query, but this checking is still a validation process, isn't it?

Validation should happen before I will save passenger(s) details.

In my application model, it is the ActiveRecord pattern object which represent a table. I would rather make Validator as a separated layer than to build it into the *Model* layer. But in this case I have an extra issue: usually Validators are general (their rules might be applied to any set of data). For instance is this data email? or IP? or date? etc.... but never mind what the data is. 
In my case, the mentioned rule won't be common at all; it will definitely be a specific rule, which can't be used by any other input data. So my question is: Is this checking still part of the validation process? 
And if yes, will Validator violate the `S` principle from the set of `SOLID`?

Comment: I doubt if it will violate anything important.  Not much different from checking to see if a user name is unique before creating a new user.  Maybe take a look at how the Symfony validation component organizes things: https://symfony.com/doc/master/book/validation.html

Comment: @Cerad do you know how to organize validation in my case with help Symfony Validator ?

Comment: Start by working through the documentation: https://github.com/symfony/Validator

Comment: @Cerad you probably did not read my original question. Symfony validator not allow you to make a db request to validate complex data. For example for e-commerce: validate is basket sum less or more defined amount? and defined amount is different for each category, means from category A you can select only for 10 USD max, form category B for 8 USD etc.. all this limitation stored in DB, do you know how to implement such case with help Symfony validator ?

Comment: Pretty sure I read the question.  And yes, Symfony validators can indeed access databases.  Perhaps a glance at the manual may be in order?

Answer (score 1):

It is validation and you should use a separate validation layer (single responsibility for input validation). Input validation isn't just data type checking, it can be much more complex. Model validation might still be needed though.

Think of input validation as whitelist validation (“accept known good”) and model validation as blacklist validation (“reject known bad”). Whitelist validation is more secure while blacklist validation prevents your model layer from being overly constrained to very specific use cases.

Invalid model data should always cause an exception to be thrown (otherwise the application can continue running without noticing the mistake) while invalid input values coming from external sources are not unexpected, but rather common (unless you got users that never make mistakes).

See also: https://lastzero.net/2015/11/form-validation-vs-model-validation/

Comment: Thanks dude. This is what I exactly did few month ago.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, these checks are validation.

Speaking from experience with a MVC pattern framework(Yii/2), I would say that you could make an abstract validator class and from there extend it into your concrete validators and call those validators from the model class. This will need a `Model->validate()` call, but having separate classes that actually check the data will not violate the `S` in `SOLID`, while `Model->validate()` will just loop through the validatos validate methods and store the error messages in an array.

Comment: you saying that case when a Validator asking model is not violation ? I think when Model validate it self it's violation already :) but I understood your point of view, thx.